# Como enviar mensagem formatada do Html para o outlook via Form

Tags: html, formatação, outlook

Estou com um pequeno problema, estou tentando enviar via Outlook um e-mail de um Send via Form, porém quando vai para o Outlook aparece todo bagunçado:
 `"comment=Ã§Ã£o sÃ£o Ã© Ã©"`.

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
    Comment:<br>
    <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Existe alguma forma para que possa ser enviado e que o texto do corpo do e-mail seja formatado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é um problema de charset.

tente adicionar isso ao cabeçalho:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Já esta 
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Teste mudar para <meta charset="Windows-1252">. Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi no PHP utilizando a seguinte função: mb_convert_encoding($comentario, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");

Comment: Usei da forma que passou apenas para o campo comentario, porém no envio do corpo do email funcionou no Firefox

Comment: mas obrigado meu amigo